# Suggested edit indicator should not be visible for my own suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I just suggested an tag wiki excerpt edit on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, and now I get this suggested edit indicator:

[image: Suggested edit indicator]

But because it is my own edit, I get "There are no items for you to review." So actually, I should not get this indicator.

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't some other edit suggested at the same time that was simply reviewed by the time you loaded the review queue?  A mod or someone with enough rep on that site to look through the history could likely indicate if there was another suggestion at around the same time.

Comment: @Servy: It was not another edit, because the indicator is still there. Also, the indicator showed up after I suggested my edit and when I looked at the review history of the latest reviewer, the latest reviewed edit by him was an edit that I also reviewed.

Comment: I think this is a feature-request rather than a bug. It's by-design that all users are shown exactly the same number there, it's just not ideal.

Comment: @OGHaza: I updated my question.